# teamviz installation error "error: libjpeg.so.62"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, error-handling, sudo

I've been downloaded `TeamViz.3.2.x64.tar.gz`
 "teamviz timer" and extract it but when i'm trying to open it this pop up

[image]

- my os : ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

**NOTE**:I Tried running it as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some library are missing btw it's noticed in the site under the description :

"Firstly you need to install necessary libraries by commands:
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libxss1`"

so copy-paste these commands in the terminal